# QueryDSL alias for subquery in unionAll

Tags: java, sql, querydsl

Is there a way to specify an alias for a subquery when using the unionAll operator?
I'm trying to write a QueryDSL query:

```
    var id = Expressions.numberPath(Long.class, "id");

    var outgoingDocuments = SQLExpressions.select(
                    QOutgoingDocument.outgoingDocument.id.as(id)
            )
            .from(QOutgoingDocument.outgoingDocument);

    var incomingDocuments = SQLExpressions.select(
                    QIncomingDocument.incomingDocument.id.as(idP)
            )
            .from(QIncomingDocument.incomingDocument);

    var unionAll = SQLExpressions.unionAll(outgoingDocuments, incomingDocuments);


    var result = querydslJdbcFragment.query(query -> query.select(id).from(unionAll).fetch());
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
bad SQL grammar [
select id
from (select OutgoingDocument.id as id from outgoing_document OutgoingDocument)
union all
(select IncomingDocument.id as id from incoming_document IncomingDocument)
]; nested exception is 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: subquery in FROM must have an alias
```

So I should somehow specify an alias for both sub-queries, but I don't know how.

Comment: Try to create your subqueries with `querydslJdbcFragment` and a the `query` instance. QueryDSL should create them properly as subqueries.